# Swagger with ocelot response status 500

Tags: swagger, ocelot

I'm creating web app for car administrations and reservations. I'm using API Gateway with Ocelot.
I've used SwaggerForOcelot, Ocelot and Swashbuckle nugets.
Here are some examples of my code:
**API Gateway Startup.cs**

```
public sealed class Startup
{ public IConfiguration Configuration { get; } public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) { Configuration = configuration; }`

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddOcelot();
        services.AddSwaggerForOcelot(Configuration);
    }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
        app.UseSwaggerForOcelotUI();
        app.UseOcelot().Wait();
    }

}
```

**ocelot.json**

```
{     "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/ocelot.json",     "Routes": [         {             "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/carReservation/{everything}",             "DownstreamScheme": "https",             "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [                 {                     "Host": "localhost",                     "Port": 30001                 }             ],             "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/carReservation/{everything}",             "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],             "SwaggerKey": "carReservations"         },     ],     "SwaggerEndPoints": [         {             "Key": "carReservations",             "Config": {                 "Name": "Car Reservation API",                 "Version": "v1",                 "Url": "https://localhost:30001/swagger/v1/swagger.json"             }         }     ],     "GlobalConfiguration": {         "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:8081"     } }
```

**CarReservation's service Startup.cs**

```
public sealed class Startup
{
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
Configuration = configuration;
}

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title =    "CarManager.CarReservation", Version = "v1" }));
    }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
    }

}
```

**CarReservation's controller**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class CarReservationController : ControllerBase
{
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetCarReservations()
{
return Ok("Car Reservations");
}

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateCarReservation()
    {
        return Ok("Car Reservation Created");
    }

}
```

However, i'm getting this error. Any help what could be wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/swiAg.png

I think I've tried everything what I could find.. The localhost:30001/swagger works as expected, however the API Gateway's swagger shows that error.